# PythonAnywhere - Are sockets allowed?

Tags: python, sockets, pythonanywhere

I have a beginner PythonAnywhere account, which, the account comparison page notes, have "Access to External Internet Sites: Specific Sites via HTTP(S) Only."

So I know only certain hosts can be accessed through HTTP protocols, but are there restrictions on use of the `socket` module? In particular, can I set up a Python server using `socket`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not PythonAnywhere support.

Comment: Try it and see, you can't be afraid to do experiments to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 6):

PythonAnywhere dev here.  Short answer: you can't run a socket server on PythonAnywhere, no.

Longer answer: the socket module is supported, and from paid accounts you can use it for *outbound* connections just like you could on your normal machine. On a free account, you could also create a socket connection to the proxy server that handles free accounts' Internet access, and then use the HTTP protocol to request a whitelisted site from it (though that would be hard work, and it would be easier to use `requests` or something like that).

What you can't do on PythonAnywhere is run a socket server that can be accessed from outside our system.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. PythonAnywhere doesn't support the socket module.