# Connecting to free pythonanywhere instance via http

Tags: python, sockets, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to talk to a web app hosted on PythonAnywhere.  It's a low-bandwidth, low frequency connection so I'm fine with an http interface -- and it works fine over http from a browser.  However, I can't seem to get to the same service running on the PythonAnywhere host running in the cloud.

If I run the server locally, this works:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
s.send('GET /check/nicky HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n') 
print (s.recv(1024))

# 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nDate: Sat, 01 Jun 2019 23:45:14 GMT\r\nServer: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.2\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 19\r\n\r\n{"nicky": [0, 120]}'
```

However if I use `socket.getaddrinfo()` on the pythonanywhere URL (to replace the address in `s.connect()` above) I get a 'bad request' response:

```
'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nServer: openresty/1.9.15.1\r\nDate: Sat, 01 Jun 2019 23:49:48 GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 179\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>openresty/1.9.15.1</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

The server functions fine if I type the same request into a browser -- but trying to do it programmatically always fails in this manner.

Is this some kind of proxy or port-forwarding magic I don't know about?  The pythonanwhere account in question is a freebie.

** In case it's not clear **  @Steffen Ulrich's diagnosis is correct.  I ended up using https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/urequests, the micropython clone of requests, and that solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, PythonAnywhere does not seem to support socket servers that are meant to be accessed outside of the PythonAnywhere system, only HTTP servers that use the WSGI protocol. For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018426/pythonanywhere-are-sockets-allowed) and [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1652/).

Comment: Thanks.  The server itself is a bottle app serving http requests. I'm trying to use it as an http microservice -- I just can't get it to respond on PA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> s.send('GET /check/nicky HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n') 
> ..
> 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nServer: openresty/1.9.15.1\r\n ...
> ```

The server is right. What you send is not a correct HTTP request. For `HTTP/1.1` the `Host` field is required in the HTTP header.

If you add this the request might work but you might run into various other troubles, like missing support for chunked response body, assumption that everything will be done in a single read ...

While you might try to deal with all of this in your own code I recommend that you use instead an existing HTTP library, like [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/).

If you really want to write your own HTTP layer I really recommend to read and understand the standard before implementing it, that's what standards are for. For `HTTP/1.1` these are [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and following RFC's.

Comment: In this case the client code is going to be running on micropython, rather than vanilla py3 -- memory is at a premium and I expect only a very minimal response (about 100 characters worth of text).   There is a micropython version or requests that I was trying to avoid.

The puzzle remains that this code works if I run the same app locally -- it's only failing when the app is hosted on PythonAnywhere

Comment: @theodox: your local server might simple ignore parts of the standard while PythonAnywhere does not. And the `Host` header is essential if multiple servers are located on the same IP and port. If you want something minimal and simpler use `HTTP/1.0` not `HTTP/1.1` because this way you don't have to deal with HTTP keep-alive (which is default on with `HTTP/1.1` but off with `HTTP/1.0`) and chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: after messing around with manually creating headers, I  found a subset implementation of requests for micropython and that did the trick. Thanks for the clue!